# Question closed because was too localized

Tags: discussion, too-localized

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056175/heapsort-program-not-working-please-correct-this-code) was closed because was too localized.

I haven't understood why, this guy has posted the code and the code wasn't working.  Why not let it be answered? I voted to reopen it, but could you explain why was considered too localized?

Now I know what too localized means, it could help only a strict subset of people and in a specific area.  But the heapsort is a so common of an algorithm, used by everyone.

Comment: That wasn't a question of "help me figure out heapsort" but rather "here's my code. Debug it". Not many people will have that specific issue, and to boot he didn't give much evidence of trying to figure t out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that this was closed as Too Localized is because few people will have the same code as him. He wasn't trying to solve a problem, but rather trying to get others to fix his code.

[simchona](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/176326/simchona) said it [pretty well](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160556/question-closed-because-was-too-localized#comment465573_160556):

> That wasn't a question of "help me figure out heapsort" but rather
>   "here's my code. Debug it". Not many people will have that specific
>   issue, and to boot he didn't give much evidence of trying to figure t
>   out

Comment: Only pretty well? :p

Comment: @simchona Amazingly :P

Comment: Ok I agree with simchona commment but not with your answer: "few people will have the same code as him".I posted several times a question providing the code which wasn't working, and never had the question closed for this.It's ok to correct code.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I never said it wasn't okay to correct code. But he basically said "here's my code: fix it". How many people are going to say that for the same code?

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri It's the difference between, "Here's my code, fix it" and "how do I Foo the Bar?  My current attempt [...] results in [...]".  An answer of the later is capable of disregarding the code entirely and just explaining how to Foo the Bar.

Answer (score 0):

Questions asking for help solving code problems can attract `too localized` close votes when they don't use good English, and they don't say what the problem actually is, and what they've done to solve it.  I've edited it for the first problem, but the OP will need to modify it for the other two.

Comment: Poor Dnglish tends to attract downvotes, and it often causes other problems, but in and of itself it generally doesn't cause closevotes.  Not stating what the problem is would make it Not A Real Question.  As to the last point, that is a contributing factor in being too localized (and also sometimes NARQ).

Comment: @Servy, it makes people think more about closing, it doesn't necessarily cause the closevotes.

Comment: It's often an indication of poor quality posts that have other more fundamental problems, and as a result a lot of posts with poor English tend to get closed, but just because there's a correlation doesn't mean it's a causation.

Comment: Yep, just a small factor.